# Trouble with Reading and Displaying File Content Correctly

Tags: java, file, readfile

My program consists of several options of what to do with user input data about shows (name, day, time). One of the options is to read a file and display its content to the user. Although this section of my program is working, it isn't displaying correctly (As shown below). Should I make changes to how the program reads the file? If there are any suggestions on what I should change about my code, I would truly appreciate it! Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
//Method loadShows
public static void loadShows() throws IOException {
    //String to find file
    String findFile, file;
    //ask for location of file
    System.out.println("Enter Show File Location: ");
    //Read input
    findFile = in.readLine();

    file = findFile + "/show.txt";

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    x = Integer.valueOf(input.readLine()).intValue();
    System.out.println("Loading " + x + " Shows");

    for(i = 0; i<=(x-1); i++) {
        name[i] = input.readLine();
        day[i] = input.readLine();
        time[i] = input.readLine(); 
    }

    for(i = 0; i<=(x-1); i++) {
        System.out.println("Name : " + name[i]);
        System.out.println("Day : " + day[i]);
        System.out.println("Time(2:30 am = 0230) : " + time[i] + "\r");
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Enter Show File Location: 
C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\MyFirstJavaProject
Loading 3 Shows
Name :  //***As you can see it isn't in order, or displayed correctly***    
Day : Suits
Time(2:30 am = 0230) : Monday

Name : 0130
Day : The Flash
Time(2:30 am = 0230) : Thursday

Name : 0845
Day : National Geographic
Time(2:30 am = 0230) : Sunday
```

Here is my file content:

```
3     
Suits
Monday
0130
The Flash
Thursday
0845
National Geographic
Sunday
0525
```

Comment: Where and how are `name`, `day`, and `time` arrays instantiated? What type/size? Are they modified anywhere else? Where do `i` and `x` come from? Your code runs fine for me (once I make it actually compile).

Comment: Everything seems to be off by one, my guess is that there is some extra new line char or empty line in the file between the row with "3" and the row with "Suits". Check the file.

Comment: The file (if you copied it exactly) contains several spaces after the `3`. This caused a runtime error for me before I removed them in my own test. Depending on how you handle them it could result in the shift you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with only one for:

```
public static void loadShows() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\adossantos\\file.txt"));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            String everything = sb.toString();
            String[] values = everything.split("\n");

            for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i+=3) {

                if(i + 3 > values.length - 1  )
                    break;

                System.out.println("Name : " + values[i + 1]);
                System.out.println("Day : " + values[i + 2 ]);
                System.out.println("Time(2:30 am = 0230) : " + values[i + 3] + "\r");
            }
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }
```

Response:

[image]

Comment: Where do you get 3 from?

Comment: He only have 3 lines before begin another

Comment: While starting at index 1 might hack the problem of everything *displaying* off by one, it ignores the fundamental problem with OP's array *being* off by one. Granted, this is probably the best solution until OP gives more information.

Comment: Also, the rest of your code seems much better and more idiomatic than OP's, but you may want to point out in your answer that the actual part that "solves" this problem is the array indexing.